# Moving the cursor in a PyQt5 text edit doesn't work

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm contributing to [Frescboaldi](https://github.com/wbsoft/frescobaldi), a PyQt5 application and experience problems interacting with the core text edit component.

It seems whatever I try I can't get either of `setPosition` or `movePosition` to work.

The code

```py
cursor.insertText("Hello")
cursor.setPosition(cursor.position() - 5)
```

properly inserts the text `Hello` in the document but leaves the cursor at the end of the inserted text (instead of moving it to the left by 5 characters). The first line proves that cursor, textedit and document are set up properly. trying `movePosition` doesn't have any effect either.

The actual goal is to insert some text, have it selected and the cursor at the end of the selection as can be seen in https://github.com/wbsoft/frescobaldi/blob/master/frescobaldi_app/cursortools.py#L179

Am I doing anything wrong here? Could this be a bug in Qt/PyQt? Or could this be an issue in PyQt**5**?

[Edit:] I've now confirmed with a minimal app example that the problem can't be in the larger construction of the application. In the following mini app neither `setPosition` nor `movePosition` has any effect - while `insertText` works well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit

def main():    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QTextEdit()
    w.setWindowTitle('Manipulate cursor')
    cursor = w.textCursor()
    cursor.insertText("Hello World")
    # neither of the following commands have any effect
    cursor.setPosition(cursor.position() - 5)
    cursor.movePosition(cursor.movePosition(cursor.Left, cursor.KeepAnchor,  3))

    w.show()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working on a local copy of the text cursor returned by [w.textCursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor). You should call [`w.setTextCursor(cursor)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setTextCursor) at the end to change the visible cursor.

A second problem is that you use the output of `movePosition` to call `movePosition` again, which is not allowed:

```
cursor.movePosition(cursor.movePosition(cursor.Left, cursor.KeepAnchor,  3))
```

should be

```
cursor.movePosition(cursor.Left, cursor.KeepAnchor,  3)
```

Note that I tested it in Qt (not PyQt), but that should not make any difference, which successfully selected `lo` of `Hello world`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. If I do this the caret is placed at the beginning, without any selection. *And* the fact that insertText() *does* work properly seems to contradict this. As far as I understand `setTextCursor` would only make sense to *change* the text edit's cursor to another or new one

Comment: `insertText` doesn't change the cursor, but the text of the text edit. You want to change (the position of) the textCursor, so you need to call `setTextCursor` as said in the documentation. Note that you you remove the nested `movePosition`.

Comment: OK, I understand. As per the movePosition thing: I don't know how that embarrassing copy&paste error slipped through ...